# How not to overwrite custom repositories when installing related packages using apt

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, 20.10

For example the google-chrome.list file and the skype-stable.list file in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d folder are overwritten when using this command:

```
sudo apt -y install google-chrome-stable skypeforlinux
```

The original skype-stable.list file contains:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/skypeforlinux-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/skypeforlinux-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
```

The overwritten skype-stable.list file contains:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

The original google-chrome.list file contains:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-archive-keyring.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-archive-keyring.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable main
```

The overwritten google-chrome.list file contains:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

There's usually an update script installed under `/etc/cron.daily/` that overwrites the `.list` file.

For example, for chrome it's `/etc/cron.daily/google-chrome`. There's some configuration possible but there's usually no way to disable updating the `.list` file entirely.

The easiest workaround is to create a copy of the `.list` file, for example `my-google-chrome.list` with the desired contents and then comment out the line in the original `.list` file (don't just delete the original `.list` file since it will get re-created).